# How can I run a MultiversX node (validator)?

Tags: blockchain, multiversx

I would like to run a MultiversX validator node on my machine, but I don't know how to do it, or where to start from. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check the documentation here: https://docs.multiversx.com/validators/system-requirements/.

You can find all the steps needed (very nice explained) for Linux and MacOs (Windows OS is not supported).

But the main steps are:

1. Install and configure Go
2. Clone the repository
3. Build the binaries
4. Creating the node’s identity
5. Copying credentials and starting the node